# Make the choice of a shiny widget disabled for the other 3 shiny widgets

Tags: r, shiny

I have the `shiny` app below with 4 inputs. They contain all the variables of the `mtcars` dataset. Now I want if a value selected for example in one input (for example mpg in 1st) this value not to be able for choice in any other input. So every time those 4 inputs will have a different value selected.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

choices <- c("Pop", "RC", "RT","R4")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("Pr", "Select the price for analysis", choices = choices, multiple = F, selected = choices[1]),
    selectInput("Pr2", "Select the price for analysis", choices = choices, multiple = F, selected = choices[2]),
    selectInput("Pr3", "Select the price for analysis", choices = choices, multiple = F, selected = choices[3]),
    selectInput("Pr4", "Select the price for analysis", choices = choices, multiple = F, selected = choices[4])
    
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$Pr, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "Pr2", choices = choices[!choices %in% input$Pr])
  })
  observeEvent(input$Pr3, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "Pr2", choices = choices[!choices %in%input$Pr3])
  })
  observeEvent(input$Pr4, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "Pr2", choices = choices[!choices %in%input$Pr4])
  })
  observeEvent(input$Pr2, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "Pr", choices = choices[!choices %in% input$Pr2])
  })
  observeEvent(input$Pr3, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "Pr", choices = choices[!choices %in% input$Pr3])
  })
  observeEvent(input$Pr4, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "Pr", choices = choices[!choices %in% input$Pr4])
  })
  observeEvent(input$Pr, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "Pr3", choices = choices[!choices %in% input$Pr])
  })
  observeEvent(input$Pr2, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "Pr3", choices = choices[!choices %in% input$Pr2])
  })
  observeEvent(input$Pr4, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "Pr3", choices = choices[!choices %in% input$Pr4])
  })
  observeEvent(input$Pr, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "Pr4", choices = choices[!choices %in% input$Pr])
  })
  observeEvent(input$Pr2, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "Pr4", choices = choices[!choices %in% input$Pr2])
  })
  observeEvent(input$Pr3, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "Pr4", choices = choices[!choices %in% input$Pr3])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

choices <- names(mtcars) # c("Pop", "RC", "RT","R4")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("Pr", "Select the price for analysis", choices = choices, multiple = F, selected = choices[1]),
    selectInput("Pr2", "Select the price for analysis", choices = choices, multiple = F, selected = choices[2]),
    selectInput("Pr3", "Select the price for analysis", choices = choices, multiple = F, selected = choices[3]),
    selectInput("Pr4", "Select the price for analysis", choices = choices, multiple = F, selected = choices[4])
    
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$Pr, {
    choices1 <- choices[!choices %in% input$Pr]
    if (c(input$Pr) %in% input$Pr2) updateSelectInput(session, "Pr2", selected = choices1[1])
    choices2 <- choices[!choices %in% c(input$Pr,input$Pr2)]
    if (sum(c(input$Pr,input$Pr2) %in% input$Pr3)>0) updateSelectInput(session, "Pr3", selected = choices2[1])
    choices3 <- choices[!choices %in% c(input$Pr,input$Pr2,input$Pr3)]
    if (sum(c(input$Pr,input$Pr2,input$Pr3) %in% input$Pr4)>0) updateSelectInput(session, "Pr4", selected = choices3[1])
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Pr2, {
    choices1 <- choices[!choices %in% input$Pr2]
    if (c(input$Pr) %in% input$Pr2) updateSelectInput(session, "Pr", selected = choices1[1])
    choices2 <- choices[!choices %in% c(input$Pr,input$Pr2)]
    if (sum(c(input$Pr,input$Pr2) %in% input$Pr3)>0) updateSelectInput(session, "Pr3", selected = choices2[1])
    choices3 <- choices[!choices %in% c(input$Pr,input$Pr2,input$Pr3)]
    if (sum(c(input$Pr,input$Pr2,input$Pr3) %in% input$Pr4)>0) updateSelectInput(session, "Pr4", selected = choices3[1])
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Pr3, {
    choices1 <- choices[!choices %in% input$Pr3]
    if (c(input$Pr3) %in% input$Pr2) updateSelectInput(session, "Pr2", selected = choices1[1])
    choices2 <- choices[!choices %in% c(input$Pr3,input$Pr2)]
    if (sum(c(input$Pr3,input$Pr2) %in% input$Pr)>0) updateSelectInput(session, "Pr", selected = choices2[1])
    choices3 <- choices[!choices %in% c(input$Pr,input$Pr2,input$Pr3)]
    if (sum(c(input$Pr,input$Pr2,input$Pr3) %in% input$Pr4)>0) updateSelectInput(session, "Pr4", selected = choices3[1])
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Pr4, {
    choices1 <- choices[!choices %in% input$Pr4]
    if (c(input$Pr4) %in% input$Pr2) updateSelectInput(session, "Pr2", selected = choices1[1])
    choices2 <- choices[!choices %in% c(input$Pr4,input$Pr2)]
    if (sum(c(input$Pr4,input$Pr2) %in% input$Pr3)>0) updateSelectInput(session, "Pr3", selected = choices2[1])
    choices3 <- choices[!choices %in% c(input$Pr4,input$Pr2,input$Pr3)]
    if (sum(c(input$Pr4,input$Pr2,input$Pr3) %in% input$Pr)>0) updateSelectInput(session, "Pr", selected = choices3[1])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Are you aware of `base::setdiff()`?

Comment: Good point. Yes, we can use `choices3 <- setdiff(choices, c(input$Pr,input$Pr2,input$Pr3))` in the first observer.